# why does the php code only fetch one digit from my two-digits-ids in the database?

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

Let's say my database's table has 11 entries, so 11 ids from 1 to 11.
The following could would echo `12345678911` - it cuts off the last digit of `10` and `11`. I wonder why and more than anything: How can I fix this?

```
foreach($resultholeIdVonAutorenWerke as $row) {
    $autor_werk_id = $row['id'];

    $test .= "$autor_werk_id[0]";
}

echo $test
```

Comment: Because of `$autor_werk_id[0]`.  You're taking the first character of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you specifically only access the first character. `$autor_werk_id` is string, not an array. When you use array syntax on a string it will return the character you specify from that string. In your case the first character because you use a key of zero.

Here's [an example](https://eval.in/1047620):

```
$string = '1234567890';
echo $string[5]; // Outputs 6
```

Remove that portion of code and it will work just fine:

```
foreach($resultholeIdVonAutorenWerke as $row) {
   $autor_werk_id = $row['id'];

   $test .= $autor_werk_id; 
}

echo $test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping you can implode the result to a string.

```
$ids = array_column($resultholeIdVonAutorenWerke, "id");
echo implode("", $ids); //1234567891011
```

Array_column grabs one column from the array and implode glues together the array items with the glue (in this case "", nothing)

Comment: He's accessing the id as an array, getting only the first character(thus working with 1 integer ID's but no more than that) - your answer has nothing to do with his question.

Comment: @Kaylined Yes it does. It's an more efficient way to do the same thing OP does. I know what OP does wrong, but to just solve the problem is "lazy" in my opinion. Giving an answer that is better is how you should answer such a question. Feel free to remove your downvote. My answer is useful as it solves the problem in a better way.

Comment: @Kaylined on meta you can read about it here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels